# PDF data to csv in one cell python

Tags: python, csv, pdf

i am exacting the text of pdf and writing it in csv but its writing each line of pdf as different row.I am using pdf miner to extract the text from pdf and csv writer to write it in CSV file.I want to write the content of one file in one cell but its writing each lines in different cells.  Any help will be much appreciated. below is my code so far.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from cStringIO import StringIO
import requests
from StringIO import StringIO
import csv
import pandas as pd
from os import listdir
# exctract pdf text
def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    # fp = file(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(path, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, 
        password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = retstr.getvalue()

    # fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
    return text
# get url from csv and download it using request module
input_file = csv.DictReader(open("pdfdata.csv"))
res=[]

for row in input_file:
    try:
        filename=row['URL'].split("/")[-1].split('.')[0]
        response=requests.get(row['URL'])
        res.append([convert_pdf_to_txt(StringIO(response.content))])# call 
       pdf extractor
        break
    except Exception as e:
        pass
fl=open('newpdfdata.csv','wb')
writer = csv.writer(fl)
writer.writerow(['text'])# write header
writer.writerows(res) # write result list to csv
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: You have to include details like, how the data extracted from pdf looks like, how the csv looks like and how you wanted it to be

Comment: @RolandSmith plz see my update thanks for highlighting

Comment: @Sunitha thanks for highlighting see my update

Comment: @Chaudhary Right now, I see that each text extract for each file is written to a cell in its own different row. What are you looking to do? Have all  each text extract in the different cells but in a single row?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule in my case each line of same file is written in different cells but same row

Comment: Maybe `convert_pdf_to_txt` returns a list in your case but that would be weird. Can you assign `convert_pdf_to_txt(StringIO(response.content))` to a name e.g. `pdf_extract` and `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` then run the program? You should get a shell where you can inspect the type of the value assigned to the name. e.g. `type(pdf_extract)` If it's a list, a quick fix will be to concat the list to a string value before appending it to the result e.g. `'\n'.join(pdf_extract)` then `res.append([pdf_extract])`